# Connecting Git Repositories + Receiving Updates

Tags: git, git-fork

I have 3 different git repositories, each having 30 some projects in them (one of them is the main one, though). What I want to achieve is, to have a way to somehow "connect" these repositories to each other, so that when someone pulls the main one, the other two will be pulled too, along with the updates. So they will share the same workspace.

I can give a use case of this maybe. Sometimes people make their own versions our of open-source projects, and somehow connect their versions to the original git repository of these project, and receive the updates whenever the original one releases. This means they somehow connect these repositories to each other (their version and the original repository). So that there is no explicit need of update, as when you pull, you get the changes in the software and keep using it.

I hope I could explain my problem. If something is unclear, please ask, I'll try to explain more in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the way of achieving this. It's the `git submodule` command (with necessary arguments) which organizes the structure  I wanted.

[Here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) is the argument page.

[Here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) is the tutorial page with examples from Git itself.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UQvXst5I41I) is a very nice tutorial video illustrating how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the google tool [repo](https://code.google.com/p/git-repo/). It allows you to manage several git repository.

Comment: Are you sure it works for desktop development? Because I have seen this "to work with Git in the context of Android."

Comment: I never used it, but I am pretty sure you can use it for any Git repository. I guess the example of Android is used because this is a Google product too.